# API (number of signatures), return signed document, signature location

Tags: docusignapi

1. Which API request should we use to define the number of signatures
2. Which API request should we use to define the coordination of the signature in the document (Should there be an API to set in page 6, start from which pixel. and signature area (For example:100 px X 100 px)
3. Which API returning the signed document

Answer (score 1):

both 1 and 2 are using the same API. You need to define specific tabs for specific recipients and part of the properties you can specify for tabs are their coordinates (X and U in pixels).
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create

You make a

```
POST /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```

And provide all the relevant information (see above link for details).

For #3 you need a different API to pull envelope documents:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

Assuming you know the documentId for the specific document you wish to retrieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Much Appreciated!

Comment: can you please mark this question as answered? thanks!